# surface area of rectangular prism given diagonal and l+w+h

Tags: geometry

Find a surface area of rectangular prism  that has diagonal of 8 unit and l+w+h=10 unit. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surface area of a rectangular prism , $A = 2(lw+wh+hl)$

Diagonal length, $d = \sqrt{l^2+w^2+h^2}$

So,

$8 = \sqrt{l^2+w^2+h^2}$

$l^2+w^2+h^2 = 64$

Also, $l+w+h= 10$

$(l+w+h)^2 = l^2 +w^2+h^2+2(lw+wh+hl)$

$100 = 64 + 2(lw+wh+hl)$

$2(lw+wh+hl) = 36$

Thus, $$A = 2(lw+wh+hl) = 36$$